# Why does my js.erb file only run in one of these situations?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following action on my controller for a Comment:

```
  def create
    @comment = comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.replyable_type = params[:replyable_type]
    @comment.replyable_id = params[:replyable_id]
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        # Removed
      end
      format.js do
        @comment.save
      end
    end
  end
```

and the following `create.js.erb` file for when it gets called by a remote form:

```
console.log('It did run');
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
  <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    console.log('<%= javascript_escape(msg) %>');
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  comment = "<%= escape_javascript render @comment %>";
  <% if @comment.replyable_type == 'Comment' %>
    $('#comment-<%= @comment.id %> > .replies').prepend(comment));
  <% else %>
    $('.comments').prepend(comment);
  <% end %>
  // removed
<% end %>
```

Along with the following form partial:

```
<%= form_for(Comment.new, url: comments_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="comment-form" id="comment-<%= replyable_type %>-<%= replyable_id %>">
    <%= f.text_area :content, cols: 60, rows: 5 %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :replyable_id, replyable_id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :replyable_type, replyable_type %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send Comment', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`replyable` is a polymorphic association, which can be either a `Post` or a `Comment` object. When I submit a copy of the form on a page for a post, where `replyable_type` is `Post` and `replyable_id` is a post's ID, it works fine. When I submit a copy of the form on the same page, with the `replyable_type` set to `Comment`, and the `replyable_id` set to a comment's ID, the view the javascript does not run, at all. The action on the controller runs, using Firebug I can see the rendered javascript being sent back in response to the post request, and the comment is added to the database.

There are no errors in either the Rails console for generating the javascript or in the Firebug console to do with running the generated javascript. There are also no errors in the `@comment.errors` array. Even the first `console.log` in the Javascript is not run when the replyable object is a comment, despite being present in the rendered javascript.

What could cause this? I am using Rails 3.2.13 on Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Where are you rendering the JS? Maybe it isn't in the code path for some reason.

Comment: `remote: true` causes the form to send an XMLHTTPRequest to the browser, and the `format.js` causes it to react to a XHR by sending the rendered `.js.erb` file with the same name as the action since I haven't told it to render something different. Given that it worked for the case where the replyable is a post and I can see the rendered JS being returned (it's just not running it), I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: if the record is saved to the db, why should it have errors?